# chronicle-bytes shared DirectBytesStores

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-bytes

I've created a `MappedBytes` instance to a file that I'm using as shared cache between different Java processes.

I would like to be able to split out additional MappedByte instances (or ByteBuffer or any other instance) from the original that provide direct read/write access to a subset of the underlying file.

I've spent today experimenting with different methods but options like `subBytes()`, `rawCopy()` and `copyTo()` all seem to create local copies of the underlying file, rather than accessing the file directly.

For example:

```
File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "data.dat");
MappedFile mappedFile = MappedFile.mappedFile(tmpfile, 1000, 100, 10, false);
MappedBytes original = MappedBytes.mappedBytes(mappedFile);
original.zeroOut(0, 1000);

original.writeInt(0, 1234);
BytesStore copy = original.bytesStore().subBytes(0, 200);

// Print out the int in the two BytesStores.
// This shows that the copy has the same contents of the original.
System.out.println("Original(0): " + original.readInt(0));
System.out.println("Copy(0): " + copy.readInt(0));

// Now modify the copy and print out the new int in the two BytesStores again.
copy.writeInt(50, 4321);
System.out.println("Original(50): " + original.readInt(50));
System.out.println("Copy(50): " + copy.readInt(50));
```

Produces the output:

```
Original(0): 1234
Copy(0): 1234
Original(50): 0
Copy(50): 4321
```

The copy has been modified but not the original. I would like the original to be modified, can chronicle-bytes do this?

Thanks for your help,
Josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-contained test which I think behaves the way you need.

```
@Test
public void multiBytes() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String tmpfile = OS.TMP +  "/data.dat";
    MappedFile mappedFile = MappedFile.mappedFile(new File(tmpfile), 64 << 10);
    MappedBytes original = MappedBytes.mappedBytes(mappedFile);
    original.zeroOut(0, 1000);

    original.writeInt(0, 1234);

    PointerBytesStore pbs = new PointerBytesStore();
    pbs.set(original.addressForRead(50), 100);

    // Print out the int in the two BytesStores.
    // This shows that the copy has the same contents of the original.
    System.out.println("Original(0): " + original.readInt(0));
    System.out.println("PBS(0): " + pbs.readInt(0));

    // Now modify the copy and print out the new int in the two BytesStores again.
    pbs.writeInt(0, 4321);
    System.out.println("Original(50): " + original.readInt(50));
    System.out.println("PBS(0): " + pbs.readInt(0));
    original.writeInt(54, 12345678);
    System.out.println("Original(54): " + original.readInt(54));
    System.out.println("PBS(4): " + pbs.readInt(4));
}
```

prints

```
Original(0): 1234
PBS(0): 0
Original(50): 4321
PBS(0): 4321
Original(54): 12345678
PBS(4): 12345678
```

Comment: Hi @Peter thanks for the fast response. This code looks like it achieves most of what I want. However it still provides the copy with full access to the entire MappedFile. I was hoping for something that would provide access to a subset of the file. Last night I did some more investigations and found the `sliceAsByteBuffer(ByteBuffer)` method which is closer to what I want. However, it gives full access to the buffer from an offset position, ideally I would like something like `sliceAsByteBuffer(ByteBuffer buf, long offset, long length)`.

Comment: It looks like the openhft.java-lang library hasn't been updated for more than 2 years and doesn't seem to work with java 10 (Not a problem for me since I'm in Java 8). Is that library still ok to use?

Comment: @BackroomGibbon I would avoid using Java Lang as we don't support it.

Comment: @BackroomGibbon see my updated example, this has two BytesStore which uses the same memory but over different ranges.

Comment: BTW we only support Java 8 and 11 (Java 10 is EOL)

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that's exactly what I want. Thanks for your help.